# I am getting error - Error: cannot find module 'cordova-common' when installing Cordova

Tags: cordova, installation

I am trying to install cordova. I simply went to the web site:
https://cordova.apache.org/#getstarted

Did step one, by installing node.js

Typed in "npm install -g cordova" at a command prompt

Then tried to type in "cordova create MyApp" as the directions state in step 2.

I get this:
Error: cannot find module 'cordova-common'

PLEASE HELP. I have tried several different ways to create the "MyApp", none worked, and I can't find anything on the internet about this issue specifically.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Follow this:

```
npm uninstall -g cordova
npm install -g cordova@latest
```

Comment: I had the same problem and this answer fixed it !

Comment: I had the error "Cannot find module 'node:events'" but the answer helped to solve the problem. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 16):

A more simple solution is to install `cordova-common` npm package (in cordova directory)

```
npm i cordova-common
```

Using the above command.

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue and I was able to solve it

Solution: 
1. Need to Change the owner of the files in your /usr/local folder to the current user

```
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local
```

2. Again install cordova

`sudo npm install -g cordova`

Now You will be able to create your file.

```
cordova create demo com.demo.test DemoApp
```

Comment: the – of the command is not a dash (-), it should be `sudo npm install -g cordova`

Comment: chown-ing a directory like that is quite risky. If it's a specific folder then it may be worth referencing that.

Answer (score 1):

Solution: Close any open development tools, such as Aptana or Eclipse. Then uninstall Node.js. Then search for any existing folders with "cordova" in name, and delete them. Then reinstall node.js and cordova per directions on web site.

Answer (score 1):

Just had this issue, the following command fixed it for me:

```
npm install -g cordova@latest
```

[For additional info](https://cordova.apache.org/news/2015/11/06/tools-release.html)

Answer (score 0):

If latest is not working:

```
npm install -g cordova@6
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete "`cordova`" folder

Delete "cordova" folder from global npm repository. For windows, generally it is at following location

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
```

2. Install cordova package

For Windows:

```
npm install -g cordova
```

For Linux:

```
sudo npm install -g cordova
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides the latest version of Cordova, I also needed to install the latest version of Cordova Android:

```
cordova platform ls
cordova platform add android@8.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

for me it solved error:

```
ionic cordova platform rm browser
```

then

```
ionic cordova platform add browser
```

Answer (score 0):

Run following inside your project which has package.json

**For Windows:**

```
# npm i cordova-common
```

**For Linux:**

```
# sudo npm i cordova-common
```

Then run:

```
# cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
```